# Prove with $\epsilon$, M that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \langle x \rangle$ $\ne$ $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, epsilon-delta

Should I prove that there exists $\epsilon$ such that for every $M \in R$ exist $x>M$ for which $\lvert \langle x \rangle - \frac{1}{2} \rvert \ge \epsilon?$ And if so, how do I do it?

Comment: What is $\left<x\right>$ ?

Comment: it is the fractional part, i.e $x - \lfloor x \rfloor = \langle x \rangle$

Comment: For the first Q, that is exactly what you need to  prove. Write out the complete definition of $\lim_{x\to \infty}<x>=1/2$ and carefully negate it and you will get exactly the sentence $\exists \epsilon >0\;\forall M\in \Bbb R\;\exists x>M\;(|<x>-1/2|>\epsilon).$

Answer (score 2):

You take $\epsilon=0.25$ (for example) and $x=n$ with natural $n>M$.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: For each $M$ exists a natural $n$ with $n>M$. For this $n$ we have $|\langle n\rangle-0.5|=|0-0.5|=0.5>0.25=\epsilon$.